# Is there a simpler way to set modal-body text by classname

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3 with Pure Vanilla JavaScript and I am able to set the `.modal-body` content using below:

```
function showBSModal(modalid, inputid) {
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById(modalid), {});
    var theValue = document.getElementById(inputid).value;
    const parent = document.getElementById(modalid);
    parent.querySelector(".modal-body").innerHTML = "Successfully Delete Uesr with ID: " + theValue;
    myModal.show();
};
```

Here I am passing `modalid` and my input box's id (`inputid`) dynamically and getting the desired output.

[image]

I tried `myModal.querySelector` instead of `parent.querySelector` but that did not work as `myModal.querySelector` is not accepted by the browser.

**Question:** Any there a better say to achieve above?

Comment: Better how? What's wrong with `parent.querySelector`?

Comment: I dont want to introduce `parent`. Was wondering if I can directly deal with the `myModal` object diretly.

Comment: Then ask that question. Asking generically for a "better" way introduces a level of opinions that is beyond what is allowed on Stack Overflow. It would also prevent you from having to ask yet another question because you didn't tell answerers that you wanted to deal with `myModal` directly before.

Comment: Gotcha. Will take care of this in future.! Sometimes we expect people would read our mind. Thanks for the suggestion by the way to make this community more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myModal` is a modal object and not an HTML element. Let's load the HTML element, store it in a variable and use that instead.

```
function showBSModal(modalid, inputid) {
    let context = document.getElementById(modalid);
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(context, {});
    var theValue = document.getElementById(inputid).value;
    context.querySelector(".modal-body").innerHTML = "Successfully Delete Uesr with ID: " + theValue;
    myModal.show();
};
```

Comment: Nice... too much to learn. !! Thanks for sharing. Worked perfectly. However I am still looking for a solution where I can deal directly with the `myModal` object. To reduce number of lines of code.

Comment: ... and this is why you don't answer generic "how do I do this better" questions ... ;P

Comment: Lol.. got it ! Thanks again. :-)

Comment: @AjayKumar in this specific case you already have the `modalid` and you need to find the context anyway before you create the modal object. Your aim is to find the element by the modal, but you already needed the element when you created the modal object, so I think that storing the `context` into a variable is a useful line. To read more about the modal object you can refer to this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: @AjayKumar if this answer solved the issue, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.